Spring Data Rest not sorting on primitive boolean type
I've an entity with boolean type property. I am using spring-data-rest and I want to sort on multiple columns. The issue is I cannot rename the property in Entity as the code is already in production.
When I pass sort column which is boolean type, the sort is ignored.
?sort=isPrimary,desc

When I pass other fields like name, it works as expected
?sort=name,desc

@Entity
public class Address{

   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private boolean isPrimary;

}

Repository

@Repository
public class AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Integer>{

   Page<Address> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}


